# Add action links in custom module page

Tags: 7, navigation

I am writing a custom module for my project which handles a list of content (from custom db table) and content addition, following is my code.

```
function cp_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/structure/package'] = array(
    'title' => t('Packages'),
        'page callback' => 'cp_packages_list',
        'access arguments' => array('administer access control'),
        'description' => t('Packages'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    $items['admin/structure/package/add'] = array(
    'title' => t('Add package'),
        'page callback' => 'cp_form',
        'access arguments' => array('administer access control'),
        'description' => t('Add package'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function cp_packages_list(){
    return 'this is a test page';
}
function cp_form() {
    return array('#markup'=>drupal_get_form('cp_my_form'));
}
```

it is working properly, but i want to show action links (add content type) at top of page like
[image]

How can i add action links on page?

my action links would be 'Add package' and 'View orders'

Answer (score 1):

```
$items['admin/structure/types'] = array(
    'title' => 'Content types',
    'description' => 'Manage content types, including default status, front page promotion, comment settings, etc.',
    'page callback' => 'node_overview_types',
    'access arguments' => array('administer content types'),
    'file' => 'content_types.inc',
  );
  $items['admin/structure/types/list'] = array(
    'title' => 'List',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,
  );
  $items['admin/structure/types/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add content type',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('node_type_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer content types'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
    'file' => 'content_types.inc',
  );
```

This is what exist on node.module, modify to set the type to MENU_LOCAL_ACTION

Hope that help.

Comment: It helps me to understand the menu structure but i am still not able to add action links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_menu_local_tasks_alter() to add action links on any page.

Output that $root_path to see what it is on a page, it is not the same as the actual path necessarily.

```
function YOURMODULE_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  switch($root_path){
    case 'admin/structure/%':
      if ($router_item['original_map'][2] == 'path_arg') {
        $item = menu_get_item('admin/structure/types/add'); 
        if ($item['access']) {       
          $data['actions']['output'][] = array(
            '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
            '#link' => $item,
          );
        }
      }
    break;  
  }  
}
```

Credit to [answer on d.o](https://www.drupal.org/node/1313132)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type for the *admin/structure/package/add* from [`MENU_CALLBACK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/7.x) to [`MENU_LOCAL_ACTION`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_ACTION/7.x). The purpose of `MENU_LOCAL_ACTION` is described in [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x).

> `MENU_LOCAL_ACTION`: Local actions are menu items that describe actions on the parent item such as adding a new user or block, and are rendered in the action-links list in your theme.

In your case, the parent item of *admin/structure/package/add* is *admin/structure/package*, which is where you want the local action to appear.

Furthermore, there isn't any need to use a function that calls a form build as page callback: Just set `'drupal_get_form'` as page callback and set `array('cp_my_form')` as page arguments.

The code to use for `hook_menu()` is the following one.

```php
function cp_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/structure/package'] = array(
    'title' => 'Packages',
    'description' => 'Packages',
    'page callback' => 'cp_packages_list',
    'access arguments' => array('administer access control'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['admin/structure/package/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add package',
    'description' => 'Add package',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('cp_my_form') 
    'access arguments' => array('administer access control'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Also, the values for the menu title and the menu description are untranslated string. The description for those values given in the documentation for `hook_menu()` is clear about that.

> **"title"**: Required. The untranslated title of the menu item.
> **"description"**: The untranslated description of the menu item.